# How do I rotate the Camera around the player by Keypress in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation, movement

I want to rotate the camera around the player by pressing E and Q but it doesnt rotates around the player. I tried RotateAround but didnt worked.

Code:

---

```
public Transform player;
public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public float rotateSpeed;
public Vector3 offset;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;


void LateUpdate () 
{
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + offset, ref velocity, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, Vector3.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(player.position, -Vector3.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Updating the **transform.position** inside *LateUpdate()* function **overrides** the effects of *RotateAround()* inside *Update()*.

*RotateAround()* actually modifies the position of the transform, hence, when you do the *SmoothDamp()* you are negating the effects of *RotateAround()*.

My suggestion would be to insert an empty game object into the hierarchy.

[image: Camera Jig <— Main Camera]

Then create two separate scripts:

**CameraFollow.cs** ( Add this to the **Camera Jig** gameobject )

```
public Transform player;
public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public Vector3 offset;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

void LateUpdate () 
{
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, player.position + offset, ref velocity, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**CameraOrbit.cs** ( Add to the **Main Camera** gameobject )

```
public Transform cameraJig;
public float rotateSpeed;

void LateUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(cameraJig.position, Vector3.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
    {
        transform.RotateAround(cameraJig.position, -Vector3.up, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

So in the end the Camera Jig is positioned where the player is and the Camera rotates around the Jig.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,Assign this code to your camera

```
[Range (0.00001f,3)]
public float speed = 0.1f;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")) * speed;
    transform.Translate (velocity);

    //Rotation
    float rotation =0;
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q))
        rotation -= 1;
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
        rotation += 1;
    transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
}
```

use Q or E button for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is an orbit camera.
Here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit with zoom")]
public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;

private Rigidbody rigidbody;

float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;

    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody != null)
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
    }
}

void LateUpdate () 
{
    if (target) 
    {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")*5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Linecast (target.position, transform.position, out hit)) 
        {
            distance -=  hit.distance;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for other purposes but not for mine, because I am using a click to move system so I want just to rotate around X Axis with Keys. But still thanks.